Repeated abusive behaviour from user
This post is mainly addressed to the moderators, martina and I.M.: bobie is a new user who is regularly engaging in abusive behaviours, launching invectives all the time in his comments and answers. I believe it is time to give him a warning. Tools are available for use by moderators, when needed. So far relations within this community have remained civilised and mutually respectful: bobie will not change unless he will be clearly requested to do so.
How many more chances to insult other users will he be granted? What is the purpose of deleting his insults, after many hours, if he continues to add new ones anyway?

@martina Thank you for considering the situation. As far as I am concerned bobie's behaviour has already become an extreme case: in my opinion the user is a trained troll and the only solution is his exclusion.
The user has recently left several insults against me, all of them simply delirious and in cold blood: I have tried to talk him through it, I only got new insults. And at the end some of his contributions were deleted by himself, others were deleted by a moderator.
What he managed to do here is shocking: he has spent an entire day to try and prove that an impersonal verb is not an impersonal verb because it is an intransitive verb (pretty much like saying that a cat is not a felid because it is a mammal). I tried to explain that, I cited the most authoritative sources, and at the end he had the nerve to say that the problem was me, that I didn't let myself be convinced (!) and that he wouldn't communicate with me any longer (i.e., in the typical language of trolls, he accused me of dishonesty).
Here he stated that an interrogative clause was not such because it was a dubitative clause (pretty much like saying that a cat is not a mammal because it is a felid). I asked him for references, I provided references: he deleted his answer outraged! (For the record: the dubitative clause is a subclass of the interrogative clause).
Here, after my positive comment to his answer, more nonsensical insults followed, in cold blood. They were deleted, eventually. It is worth recalling that one of his comments in that occasion stated that his answers were all of high standards, and the reason why he got so many upvotes on that specific one was that it was the most stupid, i.e. he was implying that the people who had upvoted that answer, but not the others, were stupid because they weren't able to appreciate his high standards.
Here, bobie's answer is incoherent gibberish that has the only purpose to deliver his insults to the users who intervened before him: martina, you must realise that is the only purpose of the user.
In his comments here he intentionally lies providing a false representation of the facts, and alternates verbal abuse and utter nonsense.
It is a full blown assault.
He has made abusive remarks against other users, included DaG and giomasce.
This is a troll who knows very well his game. I ask the moderators to consider protecting firstly the site and secondly the users assaulted by the troll.
Please note that the manner bobie cites sources and other users is intentionally fraudulent. What is happening here has no excuse.

Procedo a cancellare anche i commenti offensivi e cambio politica. Commenti accusatori e inutili saranno cancellati, ormai è passato tempo da quando ho scritto che non l'avrei fatto e non è bello lasciarli lì a deteriorare un discorso sulla lingua.

@martina Ti ringrazio per l'attenzione e ti sarò grato se vorrai anche solo tenere d'occhio la situazione.

Terrò d'occhio la situazione e altre possibili future, è la prima volta che si genera una cosa così ed è mio compito evitare che si creino flames su questo sito.

randomatlabuser, tengo l'occhio la situazione anch'io certamente. Ma devo dire che la tattica migliore è ignorare le provocazioni, mantenere la calma e non lasciarsi coinvolgere nel turpiloquio. Grazie a tutti per la vostra collaborazione.

@I.M. Secondo me non ha senso ignorare uno che ha deciso di aggredirti, specialmente se lo fa per divertimento. Che tu risponda o no, lui sa che ottiene ugualmente il suo obiettivo: danneggiare, sporcare, infastidire. E quindi continuerà a farlo.

@random, condivido, anzi, meglio sarebbe rendere pan per focaccia a questi soggetti, altro che ignorarli.

@martina I think it is a pity that all this has finished with randomatlabuser asking to be deleted form the site.

@I.M. I think it is a pity that all this has finished with randomatlabuser asking to be deleted form the site.

@Charo I haven't heard of randomatlabuster asking to be deleted! What I did was removing the offensive comments and/or answers. Where is this request?

@martina It is in his profile.

Ho notato da poco la faccenda e sto visionando lo scambio epistolare. 
Non ho ancora ben capito cosa esattamente ha scatenato il problema.
Come ho detto in un commento, non sono solita cancellare i commenti alle domande/risposte perché non credo di avere il diritto di interferire negli scambi altrui.
Per le risposte e domande invece, tendo a cancellare i toni sarcastici e punzecchiatori che reputo fuori luogo.
Naturalmente commenti o no, attaccare altri utenti per un motivo qualsiasi è ridicolo. La qualità del sito si autogenera col suo contenuto, che auto-penalizza quello scadente (attraverso i voti, sempre accompagnati, se negativi, da spiegazione). 
Trollaggi e offese ripetute non sono tollerate, prenderò misure in casi estremi come si fa su una qualunque risorsa di buon livello.
EDIT: Si veda sopra, d'ora in poi commenti offensivi e reiterati verranno rimossi. 

Grazie per questa risposta, martina, sono d'accordo completamente.


Ho notato da poco la faccenda e sto visionando lo scambio epistolare.
Non ho ancora ben capito cosa esattamente ha scatenato il problema.
Come ho detto in un commento, non sono solita cancellare i commenti
alle domande/risposte perché non credo di avere il diritto di
interferire negli scambi altrui. Per le risposte e domande invece,
tendo a cancellare i toni sarcastici e punzecchiatori che reputo fuori
luogo.
Naturalmente commenti o no, attaccare altri utenti per un motivo
qualsiasi è ridicolo. La qualità del sito si autogenera col suo
contenuto, che auto-penalizza quello scadente (attraverso i voti,
sempre accompagnati, se negativi, da spiegazione).
Trollaggi e offese ripetute non sono tollerate, prenderò misure in
casi estremi come si fa su una qualunque risorsa di buon livello.
EDIT: Si veda sopra, d'ora in poi commenti offensivi e reiterati
verranno rimossi.
Commento: Grazie per questa risposta, martina, sono d'accordo
completamente,- I.M
Commento alla domanda Sep 29: Procedo a cancellare anche i commenti
offensivi e cambio politica. Commenti accusatori e inutili saranno
cancellati, ormai è passato tempo da quando ho scritto che non l'avrei
fatto e non è bello lasciarli lì a deteriorare un discorso sulla
lingua. - Martina


Translation:

answered Sep 28 at 11:08

I became aware of the matter only a short time ago and I am reading the exchange of messages.
I already stated in a comment that I do not delete comments to questions/ answers, as I do not think I have a right to interfere with members' controversies. I limit myself to delete sarcastic or provocative sentences that I consider inappropriate, only from answers and questions,
It is 'ridiculous' to attack other members in comments or elsewhere for any reason. [literal translation impossible:] " votes and chiefly downvotes (which should always be explained in a comment) contribute to preserve the high quality of the site penalizing bad posts.
Trolling and repeated offensive words are not tolerated, I'll take steps in extreme cases, as it has to be done in any high-standard site.
EDIT Sep 29 2014 :see above, from now on offensive comments will be deleted. - Martina
Comment Sep 29 2014: Thanks Martina for this answer, I absolutely agree with you. - I.M.

Comment to the question. Sep 29: I am changing my policy, from now on I'll delete also offensive or neven on-constructive comments. Some time has passed since I declared I would not do that. It is not nice to leave such comments where they are as they spoil the debate on language.
